# How to return one random element from collection

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have this repository:

```
    List<PackageHoliday> findPackageHolidayByTypeOfPackageHolidayContains(String typeOfPackageHoliday);
```

And this controller:

```
  @GetMapping("/escortedTours")
public List<PackageHoliday> escortedToursNested() {
    return packageHolidayRepository.findPackageHolidayByTypeOfPackageHolidayContains("escortedTours");
}
```

I have one part of code that works and return me one random element, that goes like this:

```
     @Aggregation(pipeline = {"{$sample:{size:1}}"})
    AggregationResults<PackageHoliday> randomPackageHoliday();
```

But when I put `@Aggregation(pipeline = {"{$sample:{size:1}}"})` above repository method

```
@Aggregation(pipeline = {"{$sample:{size:1}}"})
AggregationResults<PackageHoliday> findPackageHolidayByTypeOfPackageHolidayContains(String typeOfPackageHoliday);
```

And then controller like this:

```
 @GetMapping("/escortedTours")
public AggregationResults<PackageHoliday> escortedToursNested() {
    return packageHolidayRepository.findPackageHolidayByTypeOfPackageHolidayContains("escortedTours");
}
```

It return all documents from collection

Comment: Try to work with indexes. You can select a random index by using `Random.nextInt(cap)` with the size of the collection as cap.

Comment: not familiar with java, but I vote that you've configured something with `@Aggregation` incorrectly. Try debug filter value actually provided to a method or print it somewhere

Comment: Your title doesn't align with your question description, and I think that's your problem in reality: You're trying to do too much in your methods. The answer to your question as titled is `PackageHoliday randomPackageHoliday = myPackageHolidayList.get(Random.nextInt(myPackageHolidayList.size());`. None of the text in your question has anything to do with the title or the solution. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MongoTemplate` to implement your aggregation pipeline.
Here is the code snippet:

```
    var match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("typeOfPackageHoliday").regex(".*" + "{matchString}" + ".*", "i"));
    var sample = Aggregation.sample(1);
    var results  = mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(match, sample), PackageHoliday.class, PackageHoliday.class).getMappedResults();
    System.out.println(results);
```

First you need to add a match stage to filter documents that contains your string in their `typeOfPackageHoliday` field:

```
var match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("typeOfPackageHoliday").regex(".*" + {matchString} + ".*", "i"));
```

Then we need to add the `sample` stage to fetch random elements from filtered documents(Here we just take **one** element from filtered documents):

```
var sample = Aggregation.sample(1);
```

And at last stich all of them together and create Aggregaton pipeline and
fetch the results:

```
    var results  = mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(match, sample), PackageHoliday.class, PackageHoliday.class).getMappedResults();
    System.out.println(results);
```

I tested this solution with a dummy collection and it worked for me.
Hope it will fix your problem

You can inject `MongoTemplate` in your classes like below:

```
@Autowire
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate
```

**Update**:
You can add this code to your controller like below:

```
public class Controller {
@Autowire
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  @GetMapping("/escortedTours")
public List<PackageHoliday> escortedToursNested() {
    return getRandomPackage("escortedTours");
}


private List<PackageHoliday> getRandomPackage(String containsText) {
var match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("typeOfPackageHoliday").regex(".*" + containsText + ".*", "i"));
    var sample = Aggregation.sample(1);
    var results  = mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(match, sample), PackageHoliday.class, PackageHoliday.class).getMappedResults();
    return results;
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying but cant make it, Idk where to put your aggregation and etc

Comment: Can you explain to me more what is your problem in implementing the above solution?

Comment: I dont know where to put that, I created new Repository and @Autowired mongo template but its says something cant wire bean... Can you tell me where to add this class by class like in my question

Comment: Add it to your controller or create a service class and put it there and return the results variable. Also, the var keyword exists in java 11 and higher.  Don't put it in Repository

Comment: I updated the answer. I think it will give a good idea how to implement it.

Comment: Could not autowire. No beans of 'MongoTemplate' type found.

Comment: `Cannot resolve method 'match' in 'Aggregation'`

Comment: Did you add spring data mongodb dependency to your project? I think the problem is with your project configuration add `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` dependency to your project. or download it from https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb/2.1.2.RELEASE/jar