# Modify mongo repository to return just one random element

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

This is my repository:

```
    List<PackageHoliday> findPackageHolidayByTypeOfPackageHolidayContains(String escortedTours);
```

This is my service:

```
  @Override
public List<PackageHoliday> getRandomEscortedTours() {
    return packageHolidayRepository.findPackageHolidayByTypeOfPackageHolidayContains("escortedTours");
}
```

This is my controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/escortedTours")
public List<PackageHoliday> getRandomEscortTours() {
    return packageHolidayService.getRandomEscortedTours();
}
```

So that for now returning me all elements that has escortedType `escortedTours`, I want to make so it return me just one random element? How I can achieve that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return one random element from collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72842746/how-to-return-one-random-element-from-collection)

Comment: No, I tried with that `@Aggregation(pipeline = {"{$sample:{size:1}}"})` but in this case that doesnt work